# Is there a way to make a latent class a predictor of a latent growth model?

Tags: panel-data, growth-model, finite-mixture-model, latent-class, growth-mixture-model

I was wondering if it is possible to run a second-order latent growth model,
where latent classes can be added as a covariate?

I have three variables of which I have 7 repeated measures, say, variable A, B, and C.
Would it be possible to run a latent class analysis with variable A and B and make that
a TIC or TVC in a second-order growth model for variable C?

The software I use is Mplus.

If anyone would inform me on

1. whether or not this model exists.
2. if this kind of model exists, what is it called?
3. any example codes or material to educate myself.

Comment: Your question could be clearer - what's a TIC, or TVC? If I've understood correctly, it can be done. I don't know if it has a name. Can you draw the path diagram? Just code the model - if you know how to do each of these models, it can be done (it's going to be kind of fiddly). If you're lucky, there will be something in the user guide that is similar.

Comment: LC software such as *Latent Gold* from Statistical Innovations offer a plethora of model solutions such as vaguely proposed in your query. See their *Publications* page for more academic ideas. https://www.statisticalinnovations.com/

Comment: Sounds like you mean you would first run the LCA separately, save the most likely class membership, and use that (class membersip) as a covariate in the LGM. You can certainly do that if it makes theoretical sense, wouldn't that just be like any LGM with a covariate? Like in MPlus User's guide example 6.10?

Comment: Thank you all so much for your comments. Sointu, you explained my intentions perfectly! I appreciate the clarification. Yes, in my mind it is pictured like the 6.10 model but I wasn't sure if latent classes could be described as a latent factor like 6.10. And since latent classes are not latent factors (at least as far as I believe), I wanted to find how to code latent class membership as a predictor (I'm not sure if latent class trajectories should be treated as time-varying or time-invariant covariances). Any ideas?

Comment: I thought of a simple situation in which you would just put in LCA membership as a covariate. If you ran the LCAs separately for each time point, you could use LCA membership as a TVC (assuming you get the same LCA structure at each time point). It's been a long time since I ran latent transition models so this may be inaccurate but I suppose you could also extract different LCA transition trajectories and create a variable indicating the trajectory for each participant and use that variable as TIC?

Comment: Thank you Sointu for this. Your words really give my abstract ideas concrete words and I really appreciate that. Yes, what I had in mind was the later case in which I would have a longitudinal (trajectory class or transition of class) class and make it as a predictor or another latent class for a trajectory. From your answer, I am assuming it is not impossible? My research area is language education but I have not seen such model. I wonder if there is a field which an analysis of this type may be applied. Anyway, thank you again! You pointed me to a direction and I may be able to get somewhere

Comment: I'm glad I could help a little. I do think it's possible to do at least something quite close to what you want. I think you'll get forward if you read about latent transition analysis studies, in your own field if they exist. Also, I think it may be possible to combine LGM and LCA/LTA, it might be called multivariate growth mixture modeling? Maybe something like [these authors](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B:JOBA.0000045341.56296.fa) did?